# Moving a website from a subdomain to the domain root

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2, apache2, httpd.conf

I have an `httpd` service on Amazon EC2 that hosts a Wordpress site on a `/wordpress` subdirectory (the WordPress is live on `https://example.com/wordpress`).

Now, I want the Wordpress site to be hosted on the root: `https://example.com/` should point to the Wordpress site.

What do you think should be done? Is it enough to copy the contents from `/var/www/html/wordpress` to `/var/www/html` folder?

Comment: Hello @vba, `https://example.com/wordpress` is not a subdomain but a subdirectory.

Comment: What files are in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory?

Comment: At a minimum, you will have to go in the Wordpress "settings" to change the "Site address" and the "WordPress address" (see [Migrating WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/upgrade/migrating/)).

Comment: Right @Éric, its from the subdirectory. Not subdomain as mentioned